# Authenticate OpenVPN against active directory from a windows server

Tags: windows, openvpn

How can I configure OpenVPN on a windows server so users can connect with the same username/password used to connect to the domain?

Comment: What research have you done prior to asking this? There appears to be ample documentation on this process. How to authenticate users with Active Directory | OpenVPN
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/how-to-authenticate-users...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not perform the basic self effort necessary.

Comment: I actually found that we can authenticate against ldap/active directory but I wanted to know if this was posible from a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a powershell script to authenticate against active directory:

```perl
$username = $env:username
$password = $env:password
$FQDN = "mydomain.internal"


#authenticate the username/password to domain
function AD-Auth([String]$uid, [String]$pwd)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $au = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('domain', $FQDN)
    $au.ValidateCredentials($uid, $pwd)
}

#check users uid/pwd
if (Ad-Auth $username $password)
{
    exit 0
}
else
{
    exit 1
}
```

And then use it in the server config:

```
script-security 3
auth-user-pass-verify "'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\\..\\adauth.ps1' via-env
```

Reference: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=26264